# Adwords - Ad disapproved - Invalid HTTP Response Code

Tags: google-ads

I created a new Adwords campaign but it's getting rejected because of the reason:

*[Destination URL] Invalid HTTP Response Code*

I used fiddler2 to see what could be up with the response codes but nothing fishy came up except maybe for an HTTP Code 302.

for those curious the page is atommagnet dot com.

Answer (score 2):

While Google Adwords do officially allow their ad links to be redirected - an HTTP 200 response code will work much better. It may be worth noting that the display URL does not need to match exactly the advert destination URL.

Perhaps you have ommitted the `www.` out of your destination URL? Your site currently redirects with an HTTP 301 code to the www subdomain if it has been omitted.